# Motion detection code {EDIT}

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, motion-detection

**EDIT**
[Human walk motion Detect](http://andisplanet.com/classprojects/CFS/cfs2.html) link explains how to detect human motion with `Opencv 2.3` on Visual Studio 2010 with C++. I downloaded the source code `motemp9.c` along with the text files `walkImgs.txt` and `output.txt` and the header `filter.h` but do not understand the following stuff.

I am having a hard time to execute this program. Can someone help me in clarifying these points?

1. In `motiontemp9.c` file, under main the files in the lines are not present. Or are these files 
   walkImgs and output?

   ```
   if((ReadFP=fopen("walk2.txt", "r")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_READ_OPEN);
   if((WriteFP=fopen("output2.txt", "w")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_WRITE_OPEN);
   ```
2. The following errors occur on running the code

   ```
   error C2660: 'cvGetSeqElem' : function does not take 3 arguments
   motemp9.cpp(186): error C2227: left of '->rect' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
   motemp9.cpp(189): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'CvScalar' to 'int'
   1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
   motemp9.cpp(218): error C2664: 'cvCircle' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int' to 'CvScalar'
   1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
   motemp9.cpp(220): error C2664: 'cvLine' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int' to 'CvScalar'
   1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
   ```

Kindly guide in what needs to be done to run this code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you reformulate your first question because I don't really get it.

```
if((ReadFP=fopen("walk2.txt", "r")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_READ_OPEN);
if((WriteFP=fopen("output2.txt", "w")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_WRITE_OPEN);
```

These two lines just check if the file exist when you run the program. If one of them doesn't exist, it returns ErrorExit

For your second question, in this example,

> Create the motion history image. This includes converting the image to grayscale, finding the difference between two frames at a time in sequence order, which creates a silhouette image of the layered history of the motion. [Implementation](http://andisplanet.com/classprojects/CFS/cfs2.html)

So you need to put in walk2.txt the path of the images that you extracted from your own video.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey,thank you for the reply. The first QUestion meant that the files provided in the webpage are walkImgs.txt and output.txt, wheras the if statements check for if((ReadFP=fopen("walk2.txt", "r")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_READ_OPEN); if((WriteFP=fopen("output2.txt", "w")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_WRITE_OPEN); So, I think it should be if((ReadFP=fopen("walkImgs.txt", "r")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_READ_OPEN); if((WriteFP=fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL) ErrorExit(ER_WRITE_OPEN);(B)I need to capture & frame my own video.How do put the path of the images extracted in walkImgs.txt, instead of wakl2.txt.

Comment: Yeah you just need to change with your value that's all.

Comment: That means the file names mentioned in the if statements in the code is incorrect?How do I write the frame numbers in the file?Also, there is this error now on using CV_RGB >> "#define CV_RGB(r,g,b) cvScalar((b),(g),(r),0) Error:no suitable conversion funtion from cvScalar to int exists". What to do? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Well the filenames were just example. 
For OpenCV, I can't help you, I don't code in C. Sorry